# jQuery: setInterval

Tags: jquery, html, caching

I want to make a slideshow on my site, but the problem is that the setInterval works only one time. It loads my file only one time end then stops.

Heres the code:
main.html

```
<img src="images/ex/full.jpg" width="800" height="377" alt="">
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var refreshId = setInterval(function(){
            $('#center').load('images/gallery/best/rotate.php');
        }, 5000);
    });
</script>
```

rotate.php

```
<img src="images/gallery/best/random.php?".<?php echo rand(0,1000) ?>."" width="800" height="377" alt="">
```

random.php contains a code which loads random image from selected folder, it works good.

Forgot to mention, I got lightbox scripts included too. Maybe they don't work together?

Head:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/js/lightbox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/lightbox.css" type="text/css" />
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that it's not actually running multiple times? Throw an alert() or console.log() in there to be sure. I wonder if it's actually caching the result of rotate.php in which case append the current time to the end of the URL.

Comment: Yea, there is nothing wrong with your code. I suspect caching.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var refreshId = setInterval(function(){
    var r = (-0.5)+(Math.random()*(1000.99));
        $('#center').load('images/gallery/best/random.php?'+r);
    }, 5000);
});
</script>
```

How about that?

--

### Edit

Sorry, I meant that you should just randomize the photos in the setInterval function.  As illustrated above.  Instead of rotate.php; just load random.php.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment, if it is a caching issue, then you can update your code with

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var refreshId = setInterval(function(){
        $('#center').load('images/gallery/best/rotate.php?' + new Date().getTime());
    }, 5000);
});
</script>
```

Which will cause the url to be different on each request and hence will avoid your caching issue.

Comment: But the image tag that is loaded will still look the same, so the image will not be reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

There problem is not the `setInterval`, it's the caching of the image. When the image tag is loaded, it looks exactly like the one before. The browser doesn't load the image again, it just uses the one that is already loaded.

If you want to load the image again, change your `rotate.php` to include a counter or random number as parameter in the URL, returning something that for example looks like this:

```
<img src="images/gallery/best/random.php?98037465936" width="800" height="377" alt="">
```

By changing the URL each time the tag is loaded, the browser has to load the new image each time.

Comment: You might also have to use the `ajax` method instead of `load`, to prevent the AJAX request to be cached: `$.ajax({cache:false,dataType:'html',url:'images/gallery/best/rotate.php',success:function(data){$('#center').html(data);}});`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that the browser has loaded random.php into the cache. I think you'd be better off giving each image it's own url and using that. Then a php page can present just the src:

```
var refreshId = setInterval(function () {
  $.get('random-src.php', function (result) {
    $('#center>img').attr('src') = result;
  },'text');
},5000);
```

Then random.php could return `img/img1.jpg`, `img/img2.jpg`, etc at random.

Alternatively, you could stick `header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");` towards the top of your random.php file to prevent the browser from caching.

Comment: The jquery code returned nothing and the header changed nothing.