# Lightweight tilt onClick / JS or CSS3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create a function where a `#div` will *TILT* 15 degrees to the left on click, and then go back to the previous position shortly after, but I think this can be easily added to the solution with adding a Timing event. But the **Tilt** is what I am having the most trouble with. Ideally I would do this with JavaScript alone; but would be open to jQuery and or CSS3.

I have used the below snippet while creating a custom shake.

```
jQuery.fn.shake = function() {
    this.each(function(i) {
        $(this).css({ "position" : "relative" });
        for (var x = 1; x <= 3; x++) {
            $(this).animate({ left: -15 }, 10).animate({ left: 0 }, 50).animate({ left: 15 }, 10).animate({ left: 0 }, 20);
        }
    });
    return this;
}
```

But it doesn't allow; or I have had no such luck --  creating a 'TILT' effect, only a horizontal or vertical side to side effect. I am assuming I may need to get some CSS3 in there. Any pointers?

*DISCLAIMER: I am hoping for a solution of primary JavaScript; as I am supporting IE 9+ / Modern Browsers (chrome, ff, safari). Otherwise there is no real point of implementing at this point. Thanks.*

Comment: tilt? You mean rotate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the "tilt" with `transform`:

```
.skew{
    -webkit-transform: matrix(1, 0, 0.5, 1,  50, 0);
    -o-transform: matrix(1, 0, 0.5, 1,  50, 0);
    -ms-transform: matrix(1, 0, 0.5, 1,  50, 0);
    transform: matrix(1, 0, .5, 1,  50, 0);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HemTH/1/

Though browser compatibility might be an issue http://caniuse.com/#search=transforms

Comment: Well according to the link, it says it's supported at IE 9 + I'm going to give this a shot!!!

Comment: So, I am working on testing this out @James Montagne - but I noticed, you created the effect in opposite. I would like to the 'Tilt' to happen on click, not visa verse.

Comment: Just remove the class initially.  http://jsfiddle.net/HemTH/2/  I was more demonstrating the tilt as opposed to trying to develop the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS3 animations and a pinch of javascript:
CSS:

```
.rotate {
    animation: rotate 10s;
    -webkit-animation: rotate 5s;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotate(15deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}
```

Javascript:

```
function shake(item) {
    item.className += "rotate";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be a good candidate for CSS animations since you can easily define your keyframes:

```
#foo {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: skewer .1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes skewer {
    0% {
        left: -15px;
        -webkit-transform: skewX(-15deg);
    }
    25% {
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: skewX(0deg);
    }
    55% {
        left: 15px;
        -webkit-transform: skewX(15deg);
    }
    100% {
        left: 0px;
        -webkit-transform: skewX(0deg);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VGGqT/

However, `.animate` takes a `step` property if its second argument is an object:

```
$(this).animate({ left: -15 }, {
    duration: 10,
    step: function (now) {
        $(this).css("-webkit-transform", "skewX(" + now + "deg)");
    }
})
```

You would have to do this for each individual animation step, so it's more verbose.

Comment: This didn't work at all for me; your jSfiddle atleast. Not in Chrome nor Firefox. I agree with the thoughts of the CSS3, and thanks for the response.

Comment: @1977 it should only work in Chrome, and it does work for me, but I'm not sure exactly what you're going for

Comment: I am seeking a solution with a minimal of modern browser support; that's why I wanted to use JavaScript the most.

Comment: This doesn't work anywhere on my side; so I can't use it with so little support as there is no point. Thanks very much, though!

Answer (score -1):

You have to use an Interval function, rather using a for-loop with the limit of 3.
There are several ways to do the Interval function in JS, you can use setInterval(?,?), and pass the function name and interval in milliseconds should do the Trick

```
setInterval(localFunction, 100);    // 1 second
setInterval(globalFunction(), 200); // 2 seconds
```

try [jQuery: setInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355076/jquery-setinterval)

Comment: You can create tilt effects by calling `setInterval()`?

Comment: it should be window.setInterval(?,?)